# Semantic MediaWiki error message not going away

Tags: mediawiki, semantic-mediawiki

The situation:

I installed an MW extension, uninstalled it again, and this broke my MediaWiki installation: The next time I viewed a page I got an error message that the SMW update key would be missing. Rebuilding the SMW database by running the SMW maintenance scripts worked to some extent: I now can get regular access to the pages again.

But now I have an error message if I view a page like this (translated from German):

```
The installation or update of Semantic MediaWiki has not yet been fully
completed. An administrator or another person with administrator rights
must therefore perform the following tasks in order to avoid data inconsistencies
before users of the wiki change existing content or create additional content:
```

And that's it. There is no text after the colon.

And there are no error messages in the logs. And there is apparently no job waiting in the job queue: Running the job script in the foreground exhibits that it is idle.

My question is: What could be wrong here? How can I get rid of this message? And why would uninstalling a simple MediaWiki extension kill the installation? Who has run into that problem before and has any hints for me?

Thank you for helping!

Comment: Have you run *MediaWiki*'s (not *SMW*'s) `maintenance/update.php`?

Comment: If you have installed SMW via composer, have you tried to remove it from your composer.json and running `composer update --no-dev` from your MediaWiki root folder?

Comment: @FO-nTTaX: Of course. But even --no-dev complained for some reason so I rebuilt the DB using the maintenance scripts from SWM. After that I had these problems.